# How to specify multiple named argument and optional argument of same name

Tags: r

How do I call a function with two arguments which both use the same name? This situation can occur when the main function has a named argument but also calls another function which itself accepts various optional arguments including one or more with the same name as the function it's being called from.

**Specifically**: I am trying to call `fviz_nbclust()` which takes an argument called *method*, and I am trying to call it with `Kmeans` (that is, `amap::Kmeans`, not base `kmeans`). Additionally, I need to pass method = 'manhattan' to the Kmeans function as I don't want the default euclidian distance. Thus I am trying to specify the *method* argument for two different contexts.

So I have tried the following:

```
fviz_nbclust(d_agg_scaled, FUNcluster = Kmeans, method = 'wss', method = 'manhattan')
```

But this returns error `formal argument "method" matched by multiple actual arguments`

The help for fviz_nbclust states that we may pass optional further arguments for FUNCluster, but I simply don't know how to tell R which *method* argument is for the main function vs the FUNcluster function.

Comment: You'll have to "cheat" a little since the package authors didn't account for this problem. Any extra arguments are passed to Kmeans directly. So if you just write `m = 'manhattan'`, the first `method = ` argument will be used by `fviz_nbclust`, and then `m = 'Manhattan'` will be passed to Kmeans, which will recognized it as the `method = ` argument since no other arguments start with m.

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely and although it's a hack, it should work in most cases. I had no idea that name shorting was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a wrapper function that takes a differently named argument that is passed to the `method` argument of `Kmeans`

Using a simple example, we can recreate your error like this:

```r
library(factoextra)
library(amap)

iris2 <- scale(iris[, -5])

fviz_nbclust(iris2, Kmeans, method = "wss", method = 'manhattan')
#> Error in fviz_nbclust(iris2, Kmeans, method = "wss", method = "manhattan")
#> formal argument "method" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

This seems to be the problem you are encountering.

Now, instead of using `Kmeans` directly, we can define a wrapper function with an argument called `my_method` that is *passed to* the `method` argument of `Kmeans`

```
my_Kmeans <- function(x, centers, my_method) {
  Kmeans(x, centers, method = my_method)
}
```

So now we can do:

```r
fviz_nbclust(iris2, my_Kmeans, method = "wss", my_method = 'manhattan')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>